# Convert a month number to month name using PowerShell

Tags: datetime, powershell

I need to convert "08" to display "August"

I can't use `Get-Date` as this is coming from a fileName which may or may not change.

So currently I split the name into an array, access the data I need, and need to convert the mm section to MMMM

```
01 = January
03 = March
etc
```

Answer (score 32):

Full month name:

```
(Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName(8)
```

Abbreviated:

```
(Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName(8)
```

Comment: I would suggest to use `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture` instead of `Get-Culture` if you want the code to work the same on different computers.

Comment: @bouvierr makes a good point. Get-Culture will get the current culture of the computer that's running the command, so 8 would be formatted as 'agosto' on computer that has the culture set to Spanish. If you want it to return 'August' at all times (no matter what the culture is), change (Get-Culture) to [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture.

Comment: Will do! thanks for the help. I guess I have one other question here and that would be - If I have a string such as 08-04-14 and I want it to return the day of the week for that SPECIFIC calender day, would you have any suggestions? - 08-04-14 would return Monday but for the year 2013 it would return Sunday (if this is easier to do in another thread I will gladly post another)

Comment: @Pmike86 (Get-Date -Month 8 -Day 4 -Year 14).DayOfWeek or [datetime]::ParseExact("08-04-14", "MM-dd-yy", [cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture) should work.

Answer (score 7):

In the spirit of using the simplest way:

`Get-Date -UFormat %B`

or to get the abbreviation for the month:

`Get-Date -UFormat %b`

This also ports over nicely from BASH and other scripting languages that use this format for dates.

Answer (score 6):

```
(Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName((Get-Date).Month)
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're looking for the current month, try this:

```
$currentMonth = Get-Date -UFormat %m

$currentMonth = (Get-Culture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName($currentMonth)
```

Comment: Adding together @bouvierr and paul-tenhoeve solutions, this is what works for me to get current abbreviated month: `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture.DateTimeFormat.GetAbbreviatedMonthName((Get-Date).Month)`

Answer (score 0):

Also try get from current **UI** culture settings in the operating system

```
(Get-UICulture).DateTimeFormat.GetMonthName((Get-Date).Month)
```